# How to get raw Mongo data results from a MongoMapper Plucky::Query object?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper, mongodb-query

Let's say we have a MongoDB collection called "images", and a MongoMapper-powered application with a corresponding "Image" model. If we set up a MongoMapper query using this model, we see that it is of type `Plucky::Query` and returns results of type `Image`:

```
>> Image.where(:file_type => 'image/jpeg').class
=> Plucky::Query

>> Image.where(:file_type => 'image/jpeg').first.class
=> Image
```

We can run the corresponding query directly on the Mongo adapter, mostly bypassing MongoMapper, by accessing the `MongoMapper.connection`. If we do it this way, the query is of type `Mongo::Cursor` and returns raw data results of type `BSON::OrderedHash`:

```
>> MongoMapper.connection.db(dbname).collection('images').find({ :file_type => 'image/jpeg' }).class
=> Mongo::Cursor

>> MongoMapper.connection.db(dbname).collection('images').find({ :file_type => 'image/jpeg' }).first.class
=> BSON::OrderedHash
```

The question is, is there a way to take a `Plucky::Query` like above and convert it to (or retrieve from it) a basic, non-extended `Mongo::Cursor` object?

At first I thought I found a solution with `find_each`, which does actually take a `Plucky::Query` and return a `Mongo::Cursor`:

```
>> Image.where(:file_type => 'image/jpeg').find_each.class
=> Mongo::Cursor
```

But it turns out this `Mongo::Cursor` is somehow extended or otherwise different from the above one because it still returns `Image` objects instead of `BSON::OrderHash` objects:

```
>> Image.where(:file_type => 'image/jpeg').find_each.first.class
=> Image
```

Update: I can't simply bypass MongoMapper query magic altogether like I did in the second case because I need to access features of MongoMapper (specifically named scopes) to build up the query, so what I end up with is a `Plucky::Query`. But then I want the results to be plain data objects, not models, because all I need is data and I don't want the overhead of model instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoMapper achieves the conversion by setting a "transformer" lambda on the plucky query. You can see this in the [MongoMapper source code](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb):

```
def query(options={})
    query = Plucky::Query.new(collection, :transformer => transformer)
    ...
end

...

def transformer
    @transformer ||= lambda { |doc| load(doc) }
end
```

So after each mongo document retrieval, this `Plucky::Query` runs the transformation that loads the model. Looking at the [Plucky source code](https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/blob/master/lib/plucky/query.rb) we see that there is a simple setter method `[]` we can use to disable this. So this is the solution:

```
plucky_query = Image.where(:file_type => 'image/jpeg')

plucky_query.first.class
# => Image

plucky_query[:transformer] = nil
plucky_query.first.class
# => BSON::OrderedHash
```

If you don't mind monkey-patching you can encapsulate like so:

```
module Plucky
    class Query
        def raw_data
            self[:transformer] = nil
            self
        end
    end
end
```

Then you could simply write:

```
Image.where(:file_type => 'image/jpeg').raw_data.first.class
# => BSON::OrderedHash
```

Answer (score 1):

If you drop to the driver, the transformer is `nil` by default:

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > Image.collection.find({ :file_type => 'image/jpeg' }, { :limit => 1 }).first.class
 => BSON::OrderedHash
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work in my case because I want to use features of MongoMapper to build up the original query. I update my question to elaborate on this point.